# Using Facebook SDK log in to go from one storyboard to another

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var loginButton = FBLoginButton(permissions: [ .publicProfile ])
        
        let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height // real screen height
        //let's suppose we want to have 10 points bottom margin
        let newCenterY = screenHeight - loginButton.frame.height - 20
        let newCenter = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: newCenterY)
        loginButton.center = newCenter

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        
        loginButton = FBLoginButton(permissions: [ .publicProfile, .email, .userFriends ])
        
        if AccessToken.current != nil
        {
        
        }
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeAfterLogIn", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeAfterLogIn")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
}
```

It asks the user to log in to Facebook in order to use the app. See images:

[image]

And this works fine. However, when the user is logged in, I need the app to get them to a storyboard called "HomeAfterLogIn.storyboard" which looks like this:

[image]

However, this is what the screen looks like after the user has signed in:

[image]

I asked this question earlier and got this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeAfterLogIn", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeAfterLogIn")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I have moved this code around my file and it has made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Did you already created and setup a facebook app?** You can do it here https://developers.facebook.com/apps/:

- Create App > set a Display Name > Create App ID
- then you need to go to Settings > Basic > scroll down till you see Add Platform and choose iOS
- put the bundle id of your iOS Project (that you can find in your Xcode > Project > Target > Bundle Identifier) and enable Single Sign ON then do Save Changes
- Roles > Test Users > Add > Create Test User > Edit > Change name/password and put a password you will remember

Take note now of the test `email` user and `password` so you can debug your app.
In Settings > Basic take note of `App ID` and `Display Name` to put in your Info.plist later.

**Make sure you added to your Podfile**:

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

Then do a `pod install` in terminal (if you haven't already installed both pods).

**In your AppDelegate.swift you should have this at least:**

```
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
            launchOptions
        )

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            options: options
        )
    }
}
```

**Right click on Info.plist and Open As > Source Code, paste this before `</dict>` :**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb{your-app-id}</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{your-app-name}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

And substitute `{your-app-name}` (once, with the Display App Name you took note before from your Facebook App Dashboard) and `{your-app-id}` (twice, as well you took note of this in the first step from your Facebook App Dashboard) in the above snippet.

**Now go to your ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if AccessToken.current != nil {
            // Already logged-in
            // Redirect to Home View Controller
            goToHome()
        }

        // Add LoginButton
        let loginButton = FBLoginButton(permissions: [ .publicProfile, .email, .userFriends ])
        let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height // real screen height
        //let's suppose we want to have 10 points bottom margin
        let newCenterY = screenHeight - loginButton.frame.height - 20
        let newCenter = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: newCenterY)
        loginButton.center = newCenter
        view.addSubview(loginButton)

        // Triggered after every successfully login / logout
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AccessTokenDidChange, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] _ in
            if AccessToken.current != nil {
                // Successfully just Logged in
                // Redirect to Home View Controller
                self?.goToHome()
            } else {
                // Successfully just Logged out
            }
        }
    }

    func goToHome() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeAfterLogIn", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeAfterLogInViewController") // I called mine like that (check screenshot below)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Make sure your HomeAfterLogIn.storyboard's ViewController (which I am not sure with what `***ViewController.swift` you linked it) has a HomeAfterLogIn `Stoyboard ID`. Eventually it should also be linked to a `***ViewController.swift` file having the same name as the ID for simplicity (HomeAfterLogIn.swift for example).

In my example I called them `HomeAfterLogInViewController` as you can see in this screenshot, both the `HomeAfterLogInViewController.swift` file and the HomeAfterLogInViewController's `Storyboard ID` but I kept the Storyboard file name as `HomeAfterLogIn.storyboard`.
[image]

If you didn't embed your `ViewController` within the `Main.storyboard` (I guess you have it there) in a `NavigationController` then you have to do it to make it work pushing into the Navigation stack another viewcontroller such as the Home...ViewController.

You can do it like this: Click ViewController from your Main.storyboard and then in the menu up go to `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`:

[image]

Comment: I have added the code above and it has made several changes. However, it will still not show the HomeAfterLogIn.storyboard, just turns the login button to a logout button. What do you mean by linking? Could you show me the code, please! Thanks!

Comment: Can you debug if `self.navigationController` is nil in your case once you reach to goToHome() function?

Comment: I updated the answer to include further step to make sure your ViewController is embedded in a Navigation Controller (I am talking about the ViewController which is displaying the LoginButton of Facebook and trying to push into the Navigation Controller stack the Home..ViewController if the user log in successfully or is loggedin already)

Comment: Just make sure to understand, the code above is not showing the HomeAlertLogIn.storyboard, but it is showing the HomeAfterLogInViewController view which is linked to HomeAfterLogInViewController.swift within the HomeAlertLogIn.storyboard. You could also have other ViewControllers in one `.storyboard`. Just to make sure that you understand.

Comment: @RossCurrie did it worked for you? I've tested it locally on my machine and is behaving correctly

Comment: Haven't had a chance to implement yet, but thank you for the help! I will reply to this post tomorrow when i have implemented it! Again thank you millions!

Comment: if the user has previously logged on, it works perfectly, however, if the user is logging in for the first time, the app will bring them to the HomeAfterLogInVeiwController on a continuous loop? Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are doing something in HomeAfterLoginViewController that is bringing you back. In my implementation locally I just use that code andit shows me the next view controller which for debugging purpose is doing nothing but only showing a blue screen. If I hit on going Back it brings me to the ViewController with the LoginFacebook button but only If I press Back in the navigation top bar.

Comment: But I think that is going outside the scope of this question, maybe it is better to ask a new question in this case and provide info on your HomeAfterLogInViewController in order to check why its coming back.

Comment: I have checked the question bc the code does work! And my HomeAfterLogInVeiwController.swift is empty apart from "import Foundation"